# Safest Connection pool in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, interface, connection-pool

I have read the code reviews on this website: this [one](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/4090/connection-pool-in-java) and this [one](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/40005/connection-pool-implementation)

So creating the pool in itself might not be that difficult, I'm more worried about the client closing the connection or the connection not being given back to the pool.

So I have tried to implement this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6595310/implementing-connection-pooling-java).

```
public interface Connection {
    Object read();
    void close();
    void rollback();
}

public class ConnectionImpl implements Connection{
    public ConnectionImpl(String connectionString) {
    }

    @Override
    public Object read() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void close() {
        // do stuff to close the connection
    }

    @Override
    public void rollback() {
        // do stuff to go back to a valid state
    }
}

/**
 * This will wrap the connectionImpl and make sure the client doesn't close the connection himself, it will instead release it
 */
public class ConnectionWrapper implements Connection {
    private Connection m_connection;
    private ConnectionPool connectionPool;

    public ConnectionWrapper(Connection connection, ConnectionPool connectionPool) {
        m_connection = connection;
    }

    @Override
    public Object read() {
        return m_connection.read();
    }

    @Override
    public void close() {
        connectionPool.release(m_connection);
    }

    @Override
    public void rollback() {
        m_connection.rollback();
    }

    @Override
    protected void finalize() throws Throwable {
        try{
            close();
        }finally {
            super.finalize();
        }
    }
}

public class ConnectionPool {
    private BlockingQueue<Connection> m_connections;
    private List<Connection> m_usedConnections;

    private int m_maxConnectionNumber;
    private String m_connectionString;

    private AtomicInteger m_currentConnectionNumber;

    public ConnectionPool(int maxConnectionNumber, String connectionString) {
        m_connections = new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(maxConnectionNumber);
        m_usedConnections = new ArrayList<>();
        m_maxConnectionNumber = maxConnectionNumber;
        m_connectionString = connectionString;
        m_currentConnectionNumber = new AtomicInteger(0);
    }

    public Connection get() throws InterruptedException {
        createNewConnectionIfNecessary();

        Connection connection = m_connections.take();
        m_usedConnections.add(connection);

        return connection;
    }

    public void release(Connection connection) {
        int usedConnectionIndex = m_usedConnections.indexOf(connection);
        if (usedConnectionIndex == -1) {
            return;
        }

        connection.rollback();
        m_usedConnections.remove(usedConnectionIndex);
        m_connections.offer(connection);
    }

    private void createNewConnectionIfNecessary() {
        synchronized(m_connections) {
            if (m_connections.isEmpty() && m_currentConnectionNumber.get() < m_maxConnectionNumber) {
                Connection connection = new ConnectionImpl(m_connectionString);
                ConnectionWrapper connectionWrapper = new ConnectionWrapper(connection,this);
                m_connections.add(connectionWrapper);
                m_currentConnectionNumber.getAndIncrement();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So, few questions:

1. is my implementation thread-safe?
2. Is there any other way my implementation could result in not releasing the connection?
3. I know that the finalize method might not be called, resulting in a Connection leaking. Is there any way to prevent this?
4. In general, any other advice?